# PHP arrays and objects together - Bad / Good Practice?

Tags: mysql, arrays, object, laravel, laravel-4

I'm fetching data from a MySQL Database. The results are returned in an object.

I can then access the data like so:

```
$db_data->row
```

In a foreach loop I alter the $db_data by adding an array, for example:

```
foreach ($db_data as $data) $db_data->row->new_data = array('key' => 'value');
```

Now the new data can be accessed with:

```
$db_data->row->new_data['key']
```

**Is this good or bad practice?**

If it's generally considered *bad practice*, what would be the right way to go to alter the database object?

---

### EDIT:

According to the comments I want to clarify the question:

I don't want to change the data in the database. What I'm doing here is adding data to the object returned by the database class in my php app (Laravel 4 btw.) .

So my question is all about ***throwing objects together with arrays*** and if it's ***good or bad practice***.

Comment: as written, that loop will write a new array to the **SAME** key in your object, overwriting the previous value.

Comment: This is neither good nor bad, it's just *practice*. But assigning an array to what seems to represent a column value seems strange: how would that transfer to the db? If it doesn't transfer, then why use a construction that is counter-intuitive?

Comment: Why not both? (array access objects)

Comment: @prix I see the point what you did there. Merci :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from my side as i see
there is nothing wrong with what you are doing
i dont consider it as a bad practice

i just think that if you know what are you doing and you will get the result that you want
never care about how are you doing it, **`just do it`** ... <kbd>^_^</kbd>

Comment: Yeah I think the same, but for this project I need to keep in mind other developers working with me on this project at a later point.

Comment: oh in this case you must use the same method that other developers use so you guys don't get confused

Answer (score 3):

As a personal opinion i don't see why it would be a bad practice.
In my view it's a natural thing you do depending on your program,
and it's not really causing confusion.

A thing that you should keep note of is that you can do `$var["key a"]` but you can't do `$obj->key a`

Comment: You've brought something new in front of my eyes. Never used the $var['key a'] variant. What would be a use case for this notation?

Comment: well sometimes the keys inside an array can have spaces, i haven't used it either but it's a valid code and in some cases it has to be considered when choosing between objects and arrays

Comment: Ah ok, will look up some more info on this when having time this evening :)

Comment: sure remember to choose the answer if it was useful :)

Answer (score 2):

To me it sounds like you are storing data in a php serialized object written to a field in a database table.

If so this makes it just about impossible to access the values from that data without getting the record and unserializing it first. Somewhat defeats the point of using a relational database.

Comment: I'm not updating the fetched database table in this case. I'm only adding data that got processed with the fetched data, which I'm then adding back to the object for use in a template (view) in Laravel 4.